# Should we add the tag "File Conversion"?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

Suggestion: I didn't see the tag "file conversion" anywhere, only "color conversion."

It seems like it could be useful and target a bit more some questions that are really related to file conversion more than the software the files was created with.

**Like for these questions, for example:**

[Create a PDF from illustrator without being able to see the individual objects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/create-a-pdf-from-illustrator-without-being-able-to-see-the-individual-objects)

[Convert Quark files to InDesign files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/convert-quark-files-to-indesign-files)

[Convert my Illustrator file-letterhead into word doc](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35093/convert-my-illustrator-file-letterhead-into-word-doc)

I think having the tag "file conversion" would make sense considering the answers, and could be added to these questions above. The "export" tag isn't always appropriate since sometimes, there's more than one software to use in order to convert a file, and there's no export at all.

Comment: You have enough rep you can create tags on your own if you think it's important

Comment: @Ryan 300 rep, as it turns out. So you should be able to make it, go-me :)

Comment: Thanks! I discovered I could simply write them in the tag field when editing heehee

Comment: @go-me http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes sense to me. Go ahead, if the tag turns out not to work or have way too little questions, we can always burninate it later.